# Python Threads not finishing

Tags: python, multithreading, threadpool

I'm currently testing something with Threading/ workpool; I create 400 Threads which download a total of 5000 URLS... The problem is that some of the 400 threads are "freezing", when looking into my Processes I see that +- 15 threads in every run freeze, and after a time eventually close 1 by 1.

My question is if there is a way to have some sort of 'timer' / 'counter' that kills a thread if it isn't finished after x seconds.

```
# download2.py - Download many URLs using multiple threads.
import os
import urllib2
import workerpool
import datetime
from threading import Timer

class DownloadJob(workerpool.Job):
    "Job for downloading a given URL."
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url # The url we'll need to download when the job runs
    def run(self):
        try:
            url = urllib2.urlopen(self.url).read()
        except:
            pass

# Initialize a pool, 400 threads in this case
pool = workerpool.WorkerPool(size=400)

# Loop over urls.txt and create a job to download the URL on each line
print datetime.datetime.now()
for url in open("urls.txt"):
    job = DownloadJob(url.strip())
    pool.put(job)

# Send shutdown jobs to all threads, and wait until all the jobs have been completed
pool.shutdown()
pool.wait()
print datetime.datetime.now()
```

Comment: Have you performed some analysis to see whether 400 threads is really improving your performance?  Threads are not free; there's some overhead associated with each thread, and the ideal number of threads could be far less than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

urlopen accepts a timeout value, that would be the best way to handle it I think.

But I agree with the commenter that 400 threads is probably way too many

Comment: I tried to see what time it took to process those 5000 urls with 5, 100, 200 and 400 threads. +- 200 was fastest.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that some of the 400 threads are "freezing"...

That's most likely because of this line...

```
url = urllib2.urlopen(self.url).read()
```

By default, Python will wait forever for a remote server to respond, so if a one of your URLs points to a server which is ignoring the [`SYN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Connection_establishment) packet, or is otherwise just *really* slow, the thread could potentially be blocked forever.

You can use the `timeout` parameter of [`urlopen()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen) set a limit as to how long the thread will wait for the remote host to respond...

```
url = urllib2.urlopen(self.url, timeout=5).read() # Time out after 5 seconds
```

...or you can set it globally instead with [`socket.setdefaulttimeout()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.setdefaulttimeout) by putting these lines at the top of your code...

```
import socket
socket.setdefaulttimeout(5) # Time out after 5 seconds
```

Comment: It worked perfectly! Thanks a lot. However, when I do this the URL will never be downloaded, what code should I add so the URL will be tried again (If possible in short code)?)

Comment: @Coryza That's a bit more complicated, because of the multi-threaded nature of the code. A quick hack would be to have a global list, and append the url to the list in the `except` block (since list appending is thread-safe). Once the `pool.wait()` returns, you can either reiterate the failed list, or just dump it to a file, bearing in mind that it's possible that those URLs may never work in the future.

Comment: @Coryza In reply to your deleted comment, it could work, but, again, some URLs may never work, so your program may never terminate. You could use a dictionary mapping the URLs to a integer, increment the integer each time you try to fetch the data from the URL, and only remove it from the dictionary once it hits a fixed retry limit.

Comment: When catching the socket error: Wouldn't this work? <pre><code>#job = DownloadJob(self.url.strip()) #pool.put(job) </code></pre>